# C++ Passing a window to a new exe

Tags: c++, windows, window, parameter-passing, exe

So my question is targeted currently at Windows, but knowing the information for OSX would still be useful just to know later incase you have the answer for that.

**How my program(s) function:**
An initial EXE will run and create a window, this EXE will check and perform updates for the main program and take some user input. After the user input this EXE will start a new EXE (the main program), passing the details from the window so that this new EXE can claim the window and use it. The first program will terminate and the window should not close.

**What I need help with:**
I know how to create the window, and passing the required arguments through the exe is not something I know, but I dont think I will struggle to find and use that information. My main question is how do I stop the Window from closing when the first EXE terminates because likely the OS will automatically start cleaning things up.

**Sidenotes:**
Its not a super big deal, I can always start a new program and recreate a window, but I think it would just be a nice aesthetic touch to not have to close the window at all, staying alive and being handled by different programs(potentially at the same time).

I am under the impression that an EXE cannot update itself while running even if the needed files/information/compiled code are not being used so if this is wrong please let me know.

Comment: You can't pass a window from one task to another. When the window owner exits, the window will close.

Comment: @MarkRansom no way to pass ownership? So am I wrong that process cant draw to windows that arent owned by it, even if it is passed the required details?

Comment: One critical component of a window is the message queue and the code for processing those messages.  That code is part of the task, and you can't transfer it to another task.

Comment: @NalydZ "*no way to pass ownership?*" - no. A window is owned by the thread that creates it, and only that thread can destroy it. If the thread ends, any windows it created that are still alive are destroyed. "*am I wrong that process cant draw to windows that arent owned by it*" - yes, you are wrong. A thread can draw on a window owned by another thread. But I would not suggest doing it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do cannot be done. You cannot transfer ownership of a window to a different thread. This can be inferred from the documentation of [`DestroyWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow):

> A thread cannot use `DestroyWindow` to destroy a window created by a different thread.

Raymond Chen expands on this as he explains in his blog entry titled [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 1: Window handles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051010-09/?p=33843):

> The thread that creates a window is the one with which the window has an inseparable relationship. Informally, one says that the thread “owns” the window. Messages are dispatched to a window procedure only on the thread that owns it, and generally speaking, modifications to a window should be made only from the thread that owns it.

As far as the OS is concerned, *nothing* survives the end of a process. This is literally the end. If you need to keep a window around, you cannot terminate the process that owns its owning thread.